# How to find the index of vector that corresponds with highest value of other vector?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector such as

```
A=[0.2 0.5 0.4 0.6]
```

that labels as the

```
A_labels=[1 2 3 4]
```

and other vector B equals

```
B=[30 10 20]
```

I assume that the highest values of vector B will be assigned for highest label in A, and reduces by order. That means

```
30 will assign for 4
10 will assign for 2
20 will assign for 3
```

I will scan all element of vector B and I want to find which labels corresponding with its based on above rule. Could you help me implement that scheme in MATLAB? Thanks

```
A=[0.2 0.5 0.4 0.6]
A_lables=1:1:size(A,2);
B=[30 10 20];
for i=1:size(B,2)
    //Find label of A_labels corresponds with B(i)
    // Result will be [4 2 3]
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want. I'm assuming `A_labels` is sorted, as in your example.

```
[~, ind] = sort(B); %// sort B and get *indices* of the sorting
[~, ind] = sort(ind); %// get *rank* of each element of B
result = A_labels(end-numel(ind)+ind);
```

Comment: Thank Luis Mendo. I test it and your method gives what I need. However, what does it means of second line in your code [~, ind] = sort(ind);

Comment: @user8430 Well, it means the same as the first: sort a vector and return not the sorted vector, but the _indices_ of the sorting. If you do this once (line `[~, ind] = sort(B);`) you get the index `ind` of the sorting of `B`. If you do that again to `ind` (line `[~, ind] = sort(ind);`) you get the _rank_ of each element of `B`, I've added comments to indicate that

Answer (score 5):

Not sure I've fully understood but can't you just sort `B` and `A_labels` descending and use the sort order from `B` as an index on the ordered `A_labels`?

So

```
[~,idx] = sort(B,'descend');
A_labels_ordered = sort(A_labels, 'descend');

result = A_labels_ordered(idx)
```