# MATLAB: Obtaining the rank ordering of a vector, with no tied ranks allowed

Tags: matlab

I've got a vector A = [6 5 7 7 4] and want to obtain the ranks as either [3 2 4 5 1] or [3 2 5 4 1] - I don't mind which. The answer is a vector in which each element is replaced by the rank it holds. This indicates to me that the fifth element is the smallest, then the second element is the second smallest, and so on.

I thought of doing `[~,~,rnk] = unique(A)`, however that doesn't work, and produces instead [3 2 4 4 1].

How can I obtain the solution with no tied ranks?

Comment: `[~,rnk] = sort(A)`?

Comment: @Divakar why not post as answer?

Comment: Would encourage OP to post an answer instead preferably with some explanation, would help him/her more that way.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will post an answer if I can work one out. However, I believe the `[~,rnk] = sort(A)` does not work. I edited the OP to remove ambiguity and clarify what I was asking.

Comment: You just need to sort again after using Divakar's answer. `[~,tmp] = sort(A);` `[~,rnk] = sort(tmp);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053822/how-to-find-the-index-of-vector-that-corresponds-with-highest-value-of-other-vec).

We use sort twice, first sorting the array to get the index and then sort the index.

```
A = [6 5 7 7 4];
[~, rnk] = sort(A);
[~, rnk] = sort(rnk);
rnk =

     3     2     4     5     1
```